# How to take a paper or .pdf atlas type map image and parse it into a data set?

Tags: image-processing

So, very basically I have an old map that I scan or have a .pdf of.

I want to write a program to take the map in as an image, analyze it, and parse out a set of data points for the roads in the map.

How would I do this conceptually? Is it possible?

Comment: Add a sample scanned image / link to the pdf

Comment: http://www.transportation.nebraska.gov/maps/docs/county%20maps/pdfs/cntydoug.pdf

Comment: For this type of input, there is no simple solution.  Although theoretically possible to do, it would be extremely difficult for someone not an expert in the field of image processing / computer vision.